# Express JS Server Shutdown after trying to print using EJS templating engine

Tags: html, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm new to Express JS, MongoDB, and I'm building a simple online shopping application using Mongoose ODM, ExpressJS, and the EJS templating engine. I have a Product model and a controller that fetches product details based on a dynamic route sent by the user. However, I'm encountering an error when accessing the product image in the EJS template.

***Product Model:***

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
const productSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    imgurl: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String,
    userID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
    },
});

export const Product = model('Product', productSchema);
```

***Product Details Controller:***

```
export function getProductDetails(req, res, next) {
    return Product.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(({ _doc }) => res.render('shop/details', { _doc }))
        .catch(console.log);
}
```

***EJS Template***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><%= _doc.imgurl %></h1>
        <img src="<%= _doc.imgurl %>" alt="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

***ERROR***
`CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "fasdf" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"`

```
  messageFormat: undefined,
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'fasdf',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONError: input must be a 24 character hex string, 12 byte Uint8Array, or an integer
```

**When I try to display the product image using the `_doc.imgurl` value within the `src` attribute of an `img` tag in my EJS template, I'm encountering the error: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "fasdf" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"." However, I'm not facing this issue when using `_doc.imgurl` within an `h1` tag.**

I'm Expecting the server to not stop while fetching this page and render it correctly.

Comment: Looks like you are using a string in place of `ObjectID`. The id in req params is `fasdf` which is not an `ObjectID`. Docs of ObjectID: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: but the request done is of type "http://localhost:3000/details/65dc383b06fa681c073a6112", here, id is a hexadecimal string

Comment: Not really sure what's happening if the id is valid but you still get the same error. Have you tried converting `_doc` to JSON when passing into `.render()`? Something like `res.render('shop/details', { _doc: _doc.toJson() })` or `{ _doc: JSON.stringify(_doc) }`